# "timing" of hiding the horizontal scrollbar in text

Tags: python, tkinter

With a small function I toggle the visibility of the horizontal scrollbar in a text widget, based on the wrap settings. Only wrap='none' it shows.
When starting the editor the bar always shows up as the default is wrap='none' and later through app.configure() is set to 'word'. The bar stays visible until I use the toggle function.

How can I intercept the 'signals of the app.configure()' to hide the bar asap? (and what is the right programmers vocabulaire for this?)

```
import tkinter as tk
class Editor(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        hsb = tk.Scrollbar(orient="horizontal", command=self.xview)
        self.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set)
        hsb.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

        if self.cget('wrap') == 'word': 
            self.hsb.configure(width=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = Editor()
    app.configure(wrap='word')
    app.pack()
    app.master.geometry('100x100')
    app.insert("end", "Nunc sit amet dictum felis, ut tempor leo.\n")
    app.mainloop()
```

Edit:added some simple code. app.configure sets wrap to word but the bar is still in 'none' or 'char' mode?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "signals of the app.configure()".  In any case, you can create the Text with any wrapping you want, and if it starts with None, the scrollbar should be visible.

Comment: @Terry Jan Reedy. I added some code, hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar does not have a mode.  There is no way to intercept configuration (at least not without delving into tcl/tk code).  If you give users of a program a way to change wrap mode, the function you link to the button or menu entry should change the scrollbar along with the wrap mode.  This statement in `__init__`

```
        if self.cget('wrap') == 'word': 
            self.hsb.configure(width=0)
```

should have `or 'char'` added to the condition and needs an else clause.  I would rewrite as

```
    self.hsb['width'] = 16 if self['wrap'] == 'none' else 0
```

and use same in any wrap-changing function.

Comment: Thanks @Terry, the code was just a mock up to illustrate the problem, I've got a working toggle outside the __init__. " intercept" was the word I'm looking for.